# Jquery inputmask Dynamic masks specific email domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a text field that requires a mask,

I am using this `jQuery` plugin to do this:  http://robinherbots.github.io/jquery.inputmask.

and with dynamic I mean that you see ______@___ and the part after the @ sign I wanted to restricted to specific domain (dynamic set it from php) meanwhile the user can type the email name.

**What do i want**: i want a way to make the mask be dynamic so when the user finish to type the input, see appended the domain address.

**What i've tried**: I tried with several masks.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Jpdd/262/

```
`$("#u_email").inputmask({
           mask: "*{1,20}[.*{1,20}][.*{1,20}][.*{1,20}]@*{1,20}[.*{2,6}][.*{1,2}]",
            greedy: false,
            onBeforePaste: function (pastedValue, opts) {
                pastedValue = pastedValue.toLowerCase();
                return pastedValue.replace("mailto:", "");
            },
            definitions: {
                '*': {
                    validator: "[0-9A-Za-z!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~\-]",
                    cardinality: 1,
                    casing: "lower"
                }
            }
    });`
```

Also I was using jquery-ghostinput-plugin but due styling and others issue didn't stay with it.

mask: `"*{1,20}[.*{1,20}][.*{1,20}][.*{1,20}]@*{1,20}[.*{2,6}][.*{1,2}]"`,

any help on inputmask mask domain

mask: `"*{1,20}[.*{1,20}][.*{1,20}][.*{1,20}]@ 'anydomainfromphpvalue' "`,

Comment: Perhaps use a different input mask that supports regular expressions?  Like https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

Comment: I had change the plugin url to the one you mention, my bad on set it up the last one.

Comment: Just tried using RobinHerbot's jquery input mask.  Using the regular expression mask, you can do something like:  $("#email").inputmask('Regex', { regex: "[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@(hotmail\.com|google\.com)" });  See http://jsfiddle.net/voqh6ek6/

Answer (score 1):

You can set it after the user inputs the data via code instead of allowing user to input the wrong domain. You can use something like bootstrap's addons (See the second [example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic)).

Comment: the domain will be set it due site preferences (PHP sessions ex).

Comment: This is not a problem, you can echo $_SESSION['domain'] wherever you want.